# ASP.Net Visual Studio Designer is looks different on browsers

Tags: asp.net, browser, visual-studio-2013, webforms

Just trying out a test web project and noticed the browser and designer views differed pretty significantly. Seemed like the font sizes and everything were a bit off.

The only thing on the page is the built-in login control and the validation summary control. I'm accessing the page right from visual studio so its just http://localhost:xxxxx.

Here's a screenshot of the issue as well as the asp code. From left to right its VS designer, Chrome, IE 11.

[image]

**Edit:** Someone sitting right next to me running the same code in VS 2013 can render the page just as it is shown in the designer. There is something up with my machine and I don't think it has to do with browser settings since they're all default and it's happening across multiple browsers.

**Edit:** What's with the downvotes?

Comment: Welcome to web development my friend.

Comment: I have added the picture/screenshot in your question, Please don't remove it during your edits.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5165388/961113) question and try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7404661/961113) answer

Comment: @Habib added the meta tag to the head and it had no effect on any browser. Issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the browser rendering defaults. You may want to look into a library such as [normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to have a more consistent view.

Comment: How is this a solution? Am I going to force all my end users to install normalize...? I think there is something going on with my machine; I tested it on another person's machine and they are rendering it normally on all browsers. (chrome, firefox, IE 11)

Comment: @Slight You do not force your users to install normalize, you just add it to your css at the start of the page. Also look at : http://www.cssreset.com/

Comment: @Aristos Gotchya, sorry that makes more sense. Still, I don't this is the route to take just yet, but it might be. It'd like to actually understand what's happening first.

Comment: @Slight What is happening is that you do not set font name, font size, and what ever else is needed, so the browser use their default settings. Work with your page and set styles with font names that are common on web browsers.

Comment: @Slight As Aristos said, the browsers all render in their own default css. This can change from browser to browser as well as from version to version. For instance, the asterisks are going to a new line in both browsers while it does not appear that way in the studio. Best practices dictate that you style these elements to be consistent across browser. This is where normalize.css helps.

Comment: @Slight, however, I do not know why VS is showing things differently, so I can't help troubleshoot that.

Comment: @Aristos Okay, but that doesn't explain why it works on my friend's setup when he runs the exact asp code in chrome.

Comment: @Slight, I'm not sure what you mean by "works". If this is a display issue then it could be cause by a number of things, including the version of Chrome he has, any style sheets, or extensions plugged in.

Comment: @BrendanMartin First, I tried out normalize.css and it did not resolve the issue. I would argue it made things look even less like the VS design preview. By "works" I'm referring to the issue of my question, that is the output doesn't look like it should as rendered by the Designer. My friend has a totally vanilla installation, we just installed these boxes yesterday.